# bot is not defined discord bot

Tags: javascript, runtime-error, discord

I am making a discord bot which will eventually be used as a rating system for the chat, but the index.js terminal says ReferenceError: bot is not defined `bot.on('ready',() =>{` I even have `const Client = new Discord.Client();`
 The code is below

```html
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Client = new Discord.Client();

const token ='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

bot.on('ready',() =>{
    console.log('This bot Is Online!');
})

bot.login(token);
```

Some people have a similar issue but mine seems to persist more hence leaving me clueless to resolve this runtime error

Answer (score 1):

`bot` should be `Client`. If you want to use the `bot` variable change `const Client = new Discord.Client();` to `const bot = new Discord.Client();`. This is your client, or the profile/user of the bot.

Its also not a good idea to reveal your bots token (if thats its actual token). Otherwise people can log into your bot with their own script and it will cause problems for whichever server that bot is in (people can kick through the bot etc.)

Comment: Thank you. I will generate a new token

Comment: Yeah, it's online now. Thanks again